# Remove first column without removing header

Tags: awk

I have a large tab delimited text file like this:

```
Item Label1 Label2 Label3 
1    Pro01  cake   wine   Toy    
2    Pro02  milk   curd   butter
3    Pro03  rice   basum  white
4    Pro04  tomma  onion  root
```

I just want to remove the contents from the first column and replace it with the second column without removing the header.

```
Item  Label1 Label2 Label3 
Pro01  cake   wine   Toy    
Pro02  milk   curd   butter
Pro03  rice   basum  white
Pro04  tomma  onion  root
```

Comment: If I have more than 10000 rows what would be the way to solve this ?

Comment: 10000 rows is really not a lot. There are many non-optimised ways that would still produce results in less than 1 second. When your file is several GB big, then it is worth considering optimised versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is:

```
awk 'NR>1{sub(/[^\t]*\t/,"")}1' file
```

Comment: Yes, but how to get rid of first column without affecting the header.

Comment: @ClaesWikner That's exactly what the script I posted does. Try it.

Comment: and I get first column intact.

Comment: Works for me, and I like how brief it is in comparison to the other answers. +1

Comment: @Claes Wikner, if your file is not actually tab delimited, then I can see this script failing as the regex used in the sub function is after all looking for any character that is not a tab, as many times as possible till it finds a tab and replace it with "".  So if you just copied and pasted the sample from the OP, it's not actually tab delimited and would fail.

Comment: Right, but just to be totally clear (yes, I'm nit-picking) it's not that the script is failing in that case, the script is still working perfectly as designed, it's just the user is running it against one format of input and expecting to see output as if they had a different format of input (i.e. the same tab-separated format that the OP requested a script to operate on).

Comment: And I copied and pasted the file and if that is wrong, how to do it?

Comment: Create a tab-separated file and run the script on it. For example, if you use `vi` then you can type the command `:g/  */s//<tab>/g` (where `<tab>` is a literal tab character) to convert all chains of contiguous blanks to tabs in any file you copy/pasted from this site.

Comment: Ed Morton, Nit-picking okay, you know what I meant, sorry for the poor wording. The script is perfect! :) (At least I knew what the regex was doing.)

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the other solution:

```
awk '{print (NR>1?substr($0,1+index($0,"\t")):$0)}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, you can simply do:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS="\t"}NR==1{print}NR>1{$1=""; print substr($0,2)}' file.txt
```

You probably want to save the output to a new file as well:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS="\t"}NR==1{print}NR>1{$1=""; print substr($0,2)}' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

And here is the command above in a structured way for better readability:

```
awk '

BEGIN {
    FS="\t";
    OFS="\t"
}
NR==1 {
    print
}
NR>1 {
    $1=""; 
    print substr($0,2)
}' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: It will remove headder also, I need to keep headder

Comment: I just fixed that. The updated version will keep the header as well.

Comment: Yes it worked and if I have N number of rows means how I can modify this command

Comment: I guess you meant to say `columns` instead of `rows`, right? If that is the case, just add more `$numbers` to `print` (each column is numbered starting at `$1`). If you really meant to say `rows`, then it doesn't matter. The command will work on all lines from the input file.

Comment: Yeah sorry for the confusion between rows/columns and my debut is if I have 500 columns, It is not possible to type $2 to $500 in the terminal right, so is there any way to slove this

Comment: I updated the answer and the new version will skip the first column and print all the rest, no matter how many columns you have.